# Multiple DataTables with same Sorting filter

Tags: javascript, datatables

Is there a way to apply the same filter to multiple DataTables? What i mean is: if I have `table A` and `table B`, and i sort `table A` by `Date`, I want `table B` sorted as well by `Date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datatable [order event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/order) and then [order](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().order()) the tableB column by the tableA order.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table1 = $('#example').DataTable();
    var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable();

    $('#example').on( 'order.dt', function () {

        var order = table1.order();

        table2
        .column( order[0][0] )
        .order( order[0][1] )
        .draw();
    } );
} );
```

See live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/k75eahxf/1/